# Web scraping odds from Betting company

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I get the same problem the URL should be http://op1.win007.com/oddslist/1726223.htm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZztyN.jpg)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://op1.win007.com/oddslist/1726223.htm"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')

containers = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "tcenter"})
print (containers)
```

After print the containers, all the company and odds shown.

How can show Bet365 odds and output the table to excel as below (Only bet365)

Bet365 3.00 3.40 2.50 32.44 28.63 38.93 97.33 0.96 1.00 0.96

Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external source. Here is the script that prints the `Bet 365` row:

```
import re
import json
import requests


url = 'http://1x2d.win007.com/1726223.js'
js_text = requests.get(url).text

game = re.search(r'game=Array\((".*")\)', js_text).group(1)
data = json.loads('[' + game + ']')

for g in data:
    g = g.split('|')
    if 'Bet 365' in g:
        print(g)
        break
```

Prints:

```
['281', '87788166', 'Bet 365', '2.75', '3.3', '2.5', '34.09', '28.41', '37.5', '93.75', '2.3', '3.4', '3.4', '42.5', '28.75', '28.75', '97.75', '0.92', '0.99', '1.05', '2019,08-1,02,18,45,00', 'bet 365(英国)', '1', '0']
```

Comment: Andrej Kesely, thanks for your reply. i also have another question. Here are the link <http://vip.win007.com/history/Odds_big.aspx?date=2020-8-5>. how can i get all the match id and apply to the script?